BufferedWriter concatena los datos a la hora de escribir en un archivo?
En mi método intento guardar una serie de datos almacenados en un HashMap en dos archivos txt. Al llamar al método no me da ningún problema o excepciones pero a la hora de ver mi archivos únicamente veo escrito el ultimo dato del HashMap.
No entiendo este comportamiento ya que dentro del método controlo la sobreescritura en una linea añadiendo .newline().
Si me podéis aclarar el error os lo agradezco.
public static void guardarAgenda(HashMap<String, String> contactos, File fileContact, File fileTelf) {
    try {

        BufferedWriter writeNombre = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileContact));
        BufferedWriter writeTelf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileTelf));
        for (String actual : contactos.keySet()) {
            writeNombre.write(actual); // escribimos el nombre
            writeNombre.newLine(); // añadimos un salto de línea después de cada contacto
            writeTelf.write(contactos.get(actual)); // escribimos el teléfono
            writeTelf.newLine(); // añadimos un salto de línea después de cada número de teléfono
        }

        // Cerramos los archivos después de terminar de escribir todos los contactos
        writeNombre.close();
        writeTelf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("ERROR GRAVE: Archivo no encontrado");
    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println("ERROR GRAVE, problemas con archivo");
    }
}


¿Posiblemente porque el FileWriter no está haciendo el append sobre los archivos? intenta: new FileWriter(fileContact,true) alli true permite agregar mas lineas sin borrar las que ya existan en el archivo.

Con los siguientes datos de prueba el código funciona de la manera esperada:
    HashMap<String,String> map= new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Pedro","1111");
    map.put("Santiago","2222");
    map.put("Marta","3333");
    map.put("Juan","4444");

Salida en fileContact:
Marta
Santiago
Pedro
Juan

Salida en fileTlf:
3333
2222
1111
4444

Como ves, se escriben todas las líneas, no la última línea como piensas.
Entonces, o tu HashMap tiene una sola línea, o simplemente estás revisando en los archivos equivocados.
Post-Data
Observarás que en mi caso, los datos no se escriben en el orden en que fueron agregados al HashMap. Esto es debido a que HashMap no garantiza que eso ocurra y el orden incluso puede variar según la versión de Java en que se ejecute el programa. Si es un requerimiento, debes considerar el uso de LinkedHashMap en su lugar o de otro objeto que sí garantice el orden, o bien ordenar previamente los elementos.
